# How to Use Where Condition With Join Query in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

Please suggest me how to I use multiple join queries with multiple where clause condition in laravel.

I have to disable use features from tables like:- my table name is **calllog** here user call records exist and another table with name **disableapp** so if user status is 1 data records show or if it is 0 data disable I do this using Joinquery.

**My Code is**

```
$callrecordings = DB::table('callrecordings')
    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'callrecordings.user_id')
    ->leftJoin('disableapp', 'callrecordings.user_id', '=', 'disableapp.user_id')
    ->select('callrecordings.*', 'users.expiry_date')
    ->where('callrecordings.user_id', '=', $user_id)
    ->where('disableapp.status', '=', 1)
    ->get();



if($callrecordings[0]->expiry_date <= Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString()){
    return response()->json(['status'=>'Package Expired Sorry!', 'data'=>'']);
} else{
    return $this->sendResponse($callrecordings->toArray(), 'Call Recordings retrieved successfully');   
}
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

I only need if disableaap table blanks then the user data list shown in records and if their status is 0 then it hides and if 1 then it will show. User is allowed to do that but the first time it will show in records.

Once i uses

```
orwhere('disableapp.status', '=', Null)
```

but it did not solve my problem soo please suggest me a solution

Thanks in advance

Comment: *`->where('disableapp.status', '=', 1)`* - this condition must be a part of LeftLoin condition, not of Where. Something like `->leftJoin('disableapp', Raw::'callrecordings.user_id = disableapp.user_id AND disableapp.status = 1')`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this solve problem? When you want to group your `where` and `orWheres` use function as parameter

```
$callrecordings = DB::table('callrecordings')
    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'callrecordings.user_id')
    ->leftJoin('disableapp', 'callrecordings.user_id', '=', 'disableapp.user_id')
    ->select('callrecordings.*', 'users.expiry_date')
    ->where('callrecordings.user_id', '=', $user_id)
    ->where(function($q){
        $q->where('disableapp.status', '=', 1)
            ->orWhereNull('disableapp.status');
    })
    ->get();



if($callrecordings[0]->expiry_date <= Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString()){
    return response()->json(['status'=>'Package Expired Sorry!', 'data'=>'']);
} else{
    return $this->sendResponse($callrecordings->toArray(), 'Call Recordings retrieved successfully');   
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer and it's working but when the status is  0 it gives this message "Undefined offset: 0" why????????????

Comment: This error is thrown in if condigion `$callrecordings[0]`. first check if any results received and then use `->first()` method to get first result `if($callrecordings->first() && $callrecordings->first()->expiry_date <= ... )`, Please upvote if you find this answer helpful

Comment: again it gives the same error message when I do status 0 in the database table